# Is there a way to start speaking a word using macOS text to speech by hovering over it and pressing a shortcut?

Tags: macos, shortcut, text-to-speech, speech

I want it to speak the word without selecting it, just hovering over it + a shortcut. Or by pressing a shortcut after using the lookup feature in Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Keyboard Maestro macro:

1. Add a double click at current mouse location action.
2. Add a press ⌥⎋ action.
   ⌥⎋ the default shortcut for ‘Speak selected text’, set in System Preferences → Accessibility → Speech. Change this to match the preference at that location.
3. Set the macro to be triggered on a hot key.

[image]

Comment: Your first step says "_Add a double click at current mouse location action._" and doesn't that select the word? The OP said "_I want it to speak the word **without selecting it**, just hovering over it..._". (Emphasis added.)

Comment: @user Yes, but I took it to mean that OP didn't want to select the word themselves and rather "just hovering over it".